# What is the requirement for bubble sort to complete in 1 pass?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, permutation, bubble-sort

I am working on a problem where you're given `n` distinct numbers, and you want to find the number of permutations such that it takes bubble sort at most 1 pass to complete.

e.g., if `n=3`, then the following permutations would only require 1 pass

```
1 2 3 
1 3 2 
3 1 2 
2 1 3
```

But

```
3 2 1 
2 3 1
```

would require more than 1 pass. Apparently the answer is `2^{n - 1}`, but I am not sure how to prove this for the general `n` case.

My question is, what are the general constraints for a sequence to allow for it to be sorted with 1 pass of bubble sort?

It is difficult for me to come up with a generic formula to generate the permutations for larger `n`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although it's an interesting question, it might be more suited to [cs.se].

Comment: In one pass of a bubble sort, an element of the array can move many positions to the right, but only one position to the left.